# How to print out a linkedList from a text file in java

Tags: java

I can't seem to figure out how to create a linked list from a text file and print out the numbers into a linked list from the text file. if Someone can help me out. what i'm missing.  This is my code

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    class InsertionSort{
      public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        LinkedList list = list(args[0]);
        System.out.println(list);
      }
      public static LinkedList list(String fileName)
                            throws FileNotFoundException
      {
        File f = new File(fileName);
        Scanner in = new Scanner (f);
        LinkedList lists = new LinkedList();
        while (in.hasNextInt()){
          int num = in.nextInt();
          lists.add(num);
        }
         in.close();
         return lists;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting a crash or an incorrect result?

Comment: Before anything, please use a generic type for `LinkedList`. Right now what you have is a raw type.

Comment: Is LinkedList a custom class of your own or are you using the built in Java LinkedList? If it's the latter you need to define the type of list.  Something like `LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();`. Similarly for all the places you declare a lined list (including the return value of your list method).